# lumen scheduler call to a member function connection() on null

Tags: laravel, eloquent, lumen

I using eloquent model in lumen scheduler but show error
**Call to a member function connection() on null**
but using DB work fine.

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Laravel\Lumen\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;
use Models\Setting;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $setting = Setting::find(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide more details. Some example code for example. The question is not clear right now.

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem, in spite of uncommented the `$app->withEloquent();` in bootstrap/app.php but still no working.

the workaround:

```php
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule) {
    // no idea why the dbserviceprovider not booted
    Model::setConnectionResolver($this->app['db']);

    // ...
}
```